# How to convert number to string in TLA+

Tags: formal-verification, tla+

Effectively, I want to build a `{"1", "2", "3", ..., "N"}` set from `1..N` set. How do I convert numbers to strings?

Comment: What do you gain from representing numbers as strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `TLC` module provides a `ToString` operator.